# Applying Metadata to Files/Folders in google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, metadata

I have been struggling to be able to append any metadata to a file in my Google Drive. Ideally, I want to append some specific metadata to a file through Google Apps Script. I have only been able to accomplish this using the following functions

```
file.setDescription(metadata)
folder.setDescription(metadata)
```

This works but the description field it still modifiable by users. Is there another way to append metadata like this?

I also tried to use the label functionality present in the Google Drive atmosphere. However, it seems these cannot be appended to files through Google Apps Scripts.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/developer-metadata

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of `This works but the description field it still modifiable by users. Is there another way to append metadata like this?`.
? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.